# Android, how fix the max character length/size of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

please guide me, i want to fix the size  of EditText..

i want that i can enter only 10 character in EditText, after that could not type any more that 10 character...

any method is there?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Accept questions in order to get any help.

Comment: You can make it with the android:maxLength row in your editText's section, in your xml. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this attribute to EditText

```
android:maxLength="10"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define max length by two ways:

#### In XML

Define attribute of edittext:

android:maxLength = "10"

#### In JAVA

Define length through programmatically:

edittext_name.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(10) });